# Google drive internet problems android phone

Tags: google-drive

I have a Samsung galaxy j1, and I have the google drive and docs apps installed. When I try to open a document from drive, I get an error. When I try to open docs, I get an error. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the few methods described to have been useful:

1. Clearing cache and data of **Google drive** and(/or) **Google+**

   - Settings >> Apps >> Google drive >> Force stop >> Clear cache and data. Do this for Google+.

After this try disabling and reenabling sync:

- Go to Settings >> Account >> Select your account >> disable Drive,  >> Goggle+, and re-enable the sync.
- Restart Google Drive.

---

2. Disabling **ipv6** in Wi-Fi settings

There is some evidence that the ipv6 setting in some routers, kills Google drive functionality, and the workaround proposed by one user was disabling the setting:

> How you do this depends on your router. In the case of my NVG589
>   router (AT&T U-verse), it turned out to be very simple: log into your
>   router as an admin, go to Home Network >> Configure. Then turn off
>   IPv6 in the dropdown and click Save. I rebooted my phone to be sure I
>   established all new connections to the router.Google Drive (Sheets and
>   Docs, too) has been working fine since.

Acknowledgements

- [Google Drive for Android won't sync over WiFi](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsToyJmHNus6_h8/?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I tried clearing the cache a few times, force stopping the app... didn't work. In the end I just uninstalled and reinstalled both apps and they're working fine now.